# How to prevent number and whitespace to pass for String in Cucumber test in Java?

Tags: java, cucumber, spring-webflux

Am new to writing Cucumber tests...

Using Java 1.8 & SpringWebFlux, I created the following checks inside my service class (which gets value from a HTTP POST request from a Spring Framework `@RestController`).

Am checking to see if `accountId` (which is a String) is not null, empty string and also cannot contain any whitespace.

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService

    @Override
    public Mono<CustomResponse> postAccount(MyRequest myRequest) {
        if (myRequest.getAccountId() == null
                    || "".equals(myRequest.getAccountId())
                    || myRequest.getAccountId().contains(" ")) {
           log.error("accountId was invalid {}", myRequest.getAccountId());
           return Mono.empty();
        }
        // Omitted if nothing failed for code brevity purposes.
    }
}
```

---

Inside my service class's integration test:

```java
@Test
void invalidAccountIds() {
    // Checks for empty string
    CustomResponse response1 = myService.postAccount(new MyRequest().accountId(""), context).block();

    // Checks for null string
    CustomResponse response2 = myService.postAccount(new MyRequest().accountId(null), context).block();

    // Checks for whitespace
    CustomResponse response3 = myService.postAccount(new MyRequest().accountId(" "), context).block();

    assertNull(response1, "accountId cannot be null");
    assertNull(response2, "accountId cannot be empty string");
    assertNull(response3, "accountId cannot whitespaces");
}
```

This completely works when doing `mvn clean install`

---

However, my Cucumber test fails:

```
@apiTest
Feature: MyService POST API test and verify response

  Scenario Outline: I verify API fields for MyService
    Given I have an jwt OAuth token
    When I make an async POST request myRequest to default:/api/v1/accounts:
    """
    Authorization: Bearer $OAUTHTOKEN
    user-agent: MyService/cucumberTest/<testCase>
    {
      "accountId" : <accountId>
    }
    """
    Then The async request MyRequest has http code <status>

    Examples:
      | testCase      | accountId             | status |
      | inputField1   |  " "                  | 400    |
      | inputField2   |  1                    | 400    |
```

---

Why do `inputField1` & `inputField2` return HTTP 200 instead of an HTTP 400?

I need accountId to always be a String and never a number...

What would I need to add in my Cucumber steps for these to become HTTP 400s?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just using Bean Validation? `@NotBlank` would Just Work. (Also, I don't generally use Webflux, but I would expect `Mono.empty()` to return an empty but successful response.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks for the quick response! Where would I append `@NotBlank`? Also, I omitted, on purpose, the part if validation is good. My integration tests using Mockito (see above) works but not my Cucumber tests. 
This is more specific to Cucumber - what do I put inside the Cucumber steps?

Comment: @Sebastiann - I didn't include the throws HTTP 400 from my `@RestController` class inside this post to make this post as concise as possible. I just need my Cucumber test to see HTTP 400. What would I put inside the Cucumber steps?

Comment: You can reply to my answer too, will be easier to see. But I think you should show your code so that it actually is what you're testing against. Right now in the code there is nowhere where a 400 is thrown, so we can't figure out why it isn't returning a 400 in the real code.

Comment: Look up _Bean Validation_. It comes in `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, throwing a custom exception right after the `logger.error()` statement would have been the solution.

What I discovered is that since I am using openapi to autogenerate these models and REST Controllers, that inside the schema yaml file, I can specify `accountId` as "required" so behind-the-scenes these validations take place.

Thanks for everyone for all the useful feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You're not throwing any exception, you're just logging an error. Any reason why you'd be expecting a 400?